# Why isn't there an Oscar for TV Series, like with the Golden Globes?

Tags: academy-awards

TV Series and the actors appearing in them are nominated for categories in the Golden Globes. So why isn't there a category for TV Series in Oscars? Is there a special policy regarding this?

Comment: Why isn't there a 'World Series' for cricket? Why doesn't FIFA hold a 'World Cup' for basketball? The 'Oscars' are for movies. Other things are for TV.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because Oscars are awards given by The Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences (AMPAS). A Motion Picture in this case refers to Movies/Films and they are ([per wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_Awards))

> to recognize excellence in cinematic achievements in the United States
>   film industry...

Golden Globes, by contrast, are ([also per wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Globe_Award))

> accolades bestowed by the 93 members of the Hollywood Foreign
>   Press Association, recognizing excellence in film and television, both
>   domestic and foreign.

Comment: Also, there are the Emmys, which are basically the Oscars for television.

Comment: @miltonaut Yes, but the Emmys are the biggest farce ever seen until the First Annual Montgomery Burns Award for Outstanding Achievement in the Field of Excellence.

Comment: There's also the Annies for animated media.

Comment: And let's not forget the Razzies.

Comment: @krillgar and the Oscars aren't?

Comment: By the logic of this answer there shouldn't be a category for best foreign film since foreign films are not a product of "the United States film industry"